# Inequivalent representations of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm looking for this result:

> A finite group has only finitely many inequivalent representations of given degree over a field of characteristic $0$.

Do someone know where I can find a proof of that? Or maybe it is easy to prove it?

I could only prove that there are a finite number of inequivalent *irreducible* representations. In the general case I cannot succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General representations of a finite group are of the form

$$\chi=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k\chi_i^{n_i}$$

with $\chi_1,\ldots, \chi_k$ the finitely many irreducible characters which uniquely determine the representation by standard theory. But then as

$$\deg \chi=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i\deg\chi_i$$

and $\deg \chi_i\ge 1$, we have

$$\deg \chi\ge \sum_{i=1}^k n_i$$

hence the number of choices such that $\sum n_i\le d$ is finite. If you want an explicit upper bound, note that if we write $(n_1,\ldots, n_k)$ for the exponent vector for $\chi$, that $1\le n_i\le d$ for all $i$, hence there are at most $d^k$ choices for the number of representations of degree at most $d$.

Comment: Just sincerely ask a fundamental problem. What does $n_i$ here mean?  the "multiplicity" of a subspace?  Thanks!

Comment: Also I think there might be a typo...it should be the direct sum of group representations and sum of characters: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Character_of_direct_sum_of_linear_representations_is_sum_of_characters